# "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" removing all fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying remove all fragments in `onStop()` of `ActionBarActivity` but this throws an exception: `Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState`. 
How could I do this ?

I'm trying this.

```
    public class CustomDrawerLayout extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    private ActionBar ab;
    private DrawerLayout dl;
    private ListView lv;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle tg;
    private LinearLayout navdrawer;

    private List<ItensListView> fragments;
    private CharSequence tl; //titulo principal
    private CharSequence tlf; //titulo fragment

    public static final String APP_NAME = "App";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_drawerlayout);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.action_bar)));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom);

        init();

        openFrag();

    }

    private void openFrag(){
        //verifica notificacao e abre o fragment correspondente
        String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url") != null ? getIntent().getStringExtra("url") : null;
        Log.i("URL_NOTIFICACAO->", url != null ? url : "");
        if(url != null) {

            if (url.equals("Noticias")) {
                selectedItem(0);
            } else if (url.equals("Eventos")) {
                selectedItem(1);
            } else if (url.equals("Tarefas") ||
                    url.equals("Advertencias") ||
                    url.equals("Agendas")) {
                Log.i("Notificacao", url);
                Log.i("LOGADO NA SESSION", SessionUsuario.isLogged(this) + "");

                if(SessionUsuario.isLogged(this)){
                    Log.i("Notificao Logado", "esta logado na area do aluno");
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    Fragment frag = AreaAlunoFrag.newInstance();
                    frag.getArguments().putString("url", url);
                    ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                    ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                    ft.commit();
                }
            }
        }else{
            Log.i("ENTREI FIRST FRAG->","ENTREEIII");
            //if(savedInstanceState == null){
                selectedItem(0);
            //}
        }
    }


    private void init(){
        //actionbar
        onConfigActionBar();
        //listview
        configItensListView();
        //drawerlayout
        dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dl);
        navdrawer = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.navdrawer);
        //listview
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);               
        lv.setAdapter(new DrawerLayoutListViewAdapter(this, fragments));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        //drawerlayout
        //dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.dl);
        //mDrawerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        //actionbardrawertoggle
        tg = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.string.drawer_open){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tl);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tlf);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        dl.setDrawerListener(tg);
        tl = tlf = getTitle();
    }

    /** ativa actionbar e botao home na action bar */
    private void onConfigActionBar(){
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        tg.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tg.syncState();
    }


     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         if (tg.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                return true;
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }



     /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_drawer_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }


    /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean status = dl.isDrawerOpen(navdrawer);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!status);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        Log.i("POSITION->", position + "");
        selectedItem(position);     
    }

    /** seleciona o fragment q sera usado */
    private void selectedItem(int position){
        FragmentTransaction ft;
        Fragment frag;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = NoticiaFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = EventoFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = LoginFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 3:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = ContatoFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 4:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = CompartilhaFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 5:
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                frag = SobreFrag.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(APP_NAME);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            default:
                closeApp();
                break;

        }

        lv.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setCustomTitle(fragments.get(position).getTexto());
        dl.closeDrawer(navdrawer);
    }

    /** define o titulo da actionbar */
    private void setCustomTitle(String title){
        //SpannableString s = new SpannableString(title);
       // s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(this, BatalhaConfigs.FONT), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        //ab.setTitle(s);
        //tl = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
        //    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
       // }else{
            super.onBackPressed();

        //}
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
    }

    /** Configura o List com as informacoes **/
    private void configItensListView(){
        fragments = new ArrayList<ItensListView>();
        //define
        ItensListView itens0 = new ItensListView("Noticias", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens1 = new ItensListView("Eventos", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens2 = new ItensListView("Área do Aluno", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens3 = new ItensListView("Contato", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens4 = new ItensListView("Redes Sociais", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens5 = new ItensListView("Sobre", R.drawable.setavermelha);
        ItensListView itens6 = new ItensListView("Sair", R.drawable.setavermelha);

        //add
        fragments.add(itens0);
        fragments.add(itens1);
        fragments.add(itens2);
        fragments.add(itens3);
        fragments.add(itens4);
        fragments.add(itens5);
        fragments.add(itens6);


        //AreaAlunoFrag

    }

    private void closeApp(){
        System.exit(0);
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }

    private void removeAllFrags(){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        for(int x = 0; x < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); x++){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fm.findFragmentById(x)).commit();
        }
        finish();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        new SendProjectId(getApplicationContext());
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(true);
        new SendProjectId(getApplicationContext());
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(false);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(false);
        removeAllFrags();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        PushControl.setIsVisible(false);
        super.onDestroy();
        CustomVolleySingleton.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(CustomVolleySingleton.TAG);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity {br.com.ferpapps.santaluzapp/br.com.ferpapps.santaluzapp.menu.CustomDrawerLayout}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3323)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1365)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1383)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:636)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:615)
            at br.com.ferpapps.santaluzapp.menu.CustomDrawerLayout.removeAllFrags(CustomDrawerLayout.java:320)
            at br.com.ferpapps.santaluzapp.menu.CustomDrawerLayout.onStop(CustomDrawerLayout.java:348)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1229)
            at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5516)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3320)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem, If you call getFragmentManager() after SaveInstaceState is called you will get an error.

change

```
 @Override
protected void onStop() {
    PushControl.setIsVisible(false);
    removeAllFrags();
    super.onStop();
}
```

to

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {
    PushControl.setIsVisible(false);
    removeAllFrags();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind according to the documentation about onSaveInstanceState "If called, this method will occur before onStop(). There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause()."   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: I changed to `fm.popBackStackImmediate()`. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove

```
finish();
```

from your `removeAllFrags()` method;